# Need Help to Understand Some Basic Java concepts about While loop conditional statements and type conversion

Tags: java

I was just trying to code a simple calculator and it works fine...

What I want to do now is include a 'do while' or 'while' loop to repeat a statement till a user enters one of the four basic operator signs. I have achieved it using other methods (if and switch) but I want to simplify it.

Also I faced a lot of problems learning how to parse a character in `scanner` and `JPane` methods. I could achieve using various resources on the internet but a simple method that would help me understand the logic more clearly and not just achieve will be highly appreciated...

```
    public class MyCalculator{
    public static void main (String [] args){

    // Let us code a simple calculator
    char OP;
    System.out.println("This is a simple calculator that will do basic calculations such as :\nAddition, Multiplication, Substraction and Division.");

    // Create a scanner object to Read user Input.
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Any positive number followed by pressing ENTER.");
    int firstNum = input.nextInt();

    // Need to Loop the below statement till one of the four (+,-,*,/) operator is entered.

    System.out.println("Enter your choice of OPERATOR sign followed by pressing ENTER.");
    OP = input.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.println("Enter your Second number followed by an ENTER stroke.");
    int secNum = input.nextInt();

    // Various possible Resolution
    int RSum = firstNum+secNum;
    int RSubs= firstNum-secNum;
    int RPro = firstNum*secNum;
    double DPro = firstNum/secNum;

    // Conditional statements for Processing
    Switch (OP){ 
    case '+': System.out.println("The Resulting sum is "+ RSum);
    break;
    case '-': System.out.println("The Resulting sum is "+ RSubs);
    break;
    case '*': System.out.println("The Resulting Product is "+ RPro);
    break;
    case '/': System.out.println("The Resulting Divisional product is "+ DPro);
    break;
    default : System.out.println("Try Again");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `OP = input.next().charAt(0);` always getting `\r` or `\n`?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question.

Comment: You probably don't want a `while` loop if your goal is to use a `JPane` or any Swing component.  Just for the question asked though, it would help if you attempted the code yourself.  At least add a `while` loop to the code above and let us have a look at what the problem is.

Comment: @markspace Thank you for the advice. Actually I tried but failed miserably with errors so I just presented the working code. I was hoping someone could add that required loop for me with some explanation

Comment: It would be better for us at least to see your attempt, rather than not understand what the problem is.

Comment: @markspace The problem is as simple as mentioned... Need help to understand and implement a while loop so that an input other than the four basic mathematical operators would result (true) until one of the operators is entered. When the conditional statement turns (false) the result statements will be executed and display the result based on the operator input. Something like " while (OP != '+' && OP !='-') "... but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
  //some code
   int number = scanner.NextInt();
}
```

But I would implement a calculator as follow:

```
int num1 = scanner.NextInt();
String op = scanner.Next();
int num2 = scanner.NextInt();
```

You can loop through a String as follow and do your checks:

```
for (char ch : exampleString.toCharArray()){
  System.out.println(ch);
}
```

You can also loop through a String as follow:

```
for (int i=0; i<examplestring.length(); i++) {
  char c = examplestring.charAt(i);
}
```

You can loop until you get a + or a - as follow:

```
char operator;    
do {
  char operator = scanner.next().get(0);
}while(operator != '+' || operator != '-')
```

You can loop and print error messages as follow:

```
char operator;
do {
  char operator = scanner.next().get(0);
  if(!isValidOperator(operator)) {
    System.out.println("invalid operator");
  }
}while(!isValidOperator(operator))

public boolean isValidOperator(char operator) {
  if(operator == '+') {
    return true;
  } else if (operator == '-') {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input. Actually we cannot use initiate OP as a String as we are going to read the signs (+, -, *, / etc) which are char type. I am not familiar with the while and do while loops. I could work with if, and switch but it s very leghty and not convinient, I am looking at something like this ... while (OP != '+' and so on )

Comment: Added some code for you too loop until you get a + or a -

Comment: thanks a lot, got it working! By the way is there a way I can change my message from " Enter an operator" to "Invalid, enter a valid operator" once the user inputs a wrong character? (out of topic actually).